# Objective-C programming

Tags: objective-c

```
*warning: iteration 5u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]                                                                                                                                                        
if([user1 isEqualToString:account1[i].name])                                                                                                                                                                                                       
^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
main.m:33:2: note: containing loop                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
```

^
please somebody correct this code

Comment: Show the declaration of `account` and show how it's populated.

Comment: If you need comments on closing brackets indicating what they are closing you have to seriously rethink your coding.

Comment: "Correct the code"? What is it suppose to do? Do you get an error? What's the unwanted scenario/results.?

Comment: Why what is wrong with it? What errors are you getting? I have edited the code to meet some sort of format for this site but you have some random brackets in there and I'm not sure if they are meant to be part of your code or not. Then the last part I could figure out if that was code or something else. Please format your question properly and ask an actual question and show us you have attempted to solve your own problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Almost certainly you have:

```
Thing account1[6] = { ... };
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)    
{  
    if ([user1 isEqualToString:account1[i].name])
```

and the compiler knows that `<= 6` will go beyond the bounds of the array (last index is 5 not 6).

To correct:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
              ^
```